# cannot create and modified variable in java

Tags: javafx

I tried to modify a String variable in java but I get that error:
Local Variable defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final 
(And I can't make it final because I want to modify it)

```html
private void get_dt(){
    String a="";

    pop_hs.setOnAction((event)->{
        if(pop_hs.isSelected()==true){
            if(a.indexOf("and")!=-1) {
                a+="or ";
                System.out.println("okkk"+a);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables outside threads on listener must be declare as final so computer can know they are not being changed or modified.

1. You can either make it a global variable
2. You can make it a variable inside on action
3. you can make it final as Final a="value";